# Laravel sessions not working on server

Tags: php, laravel, session, server

I'm trying to login to my website, but the sessions are lost when reroute or change the page. 
This is a problem that arose a few days ago, everything was working correctly for some months, but now that has not happened. Achievement not log into my server, but in my local machine everything works perfectly.

Controller

```
public function Login(){
    $data = Input::only('email','password','remember');
    $credentials['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password']];


    if (Auth::attempt($credentials,$data['remember']))
    {
        return Redirect::back();
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::back()->with('login_error', 1);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Does remote server has different version of Laravel installed? If yes, what are the versions (local & remote). You can use `php artisan -v` to check the version.

Comment: Is `storage/framework/sessions` writable if you're using the `file` driver for sessions?

Comment: No, is the same version. 4.2.19

Comment: Yes, i´m using file driver. :(

Comment: Is your PHP version the same?

Comment: The sessions are created on storage/sessions

Comment: Local 5.5.12, Server 5.5.30.

Answer (score 4):

I needed to

```
chmod -R a+rw storage/
```

to get my sessions to work.

Comment: Thank you so much i was also stuck 2 hours applied different things but all in vain.
just got this solution again thanks thanks and thanks

Answer (score 0):

In app/config/session.php file once check the driver that you are using. Change it to supported drivers like native, memcached, array etc and give a try it may work.